# How to make multiple file selection in richfacs fileupload?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I would like to select multiple file in `Richfaces` file upload. I did a small project for `Richfaces File Upload` like [this](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=fileUpload). But I cannot select multiple file in file chooser dialog box. How can I do for multiple selection?

Comment: Currently, RichFaces doesn't provide that support. It would be better to look on [PrimeFaces Upload](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/fileUploadMultiple.jsf) component that's based on [blueimp jquery file upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). Note that even using this component, you can't user multiple file selection on IE.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/thread/13291?_sscc=t

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are after something like this;

https://github.com/77mithila/jQuery-File-Upload

This allows multiple file upload and since it is opensource in GitHub, you can make a customized version of yours using the base of this.

Hope this helps :-)